# Only allow 2 digits in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I need regex that only allows a **maximum** of 2 digits (or whatever the desired limit is actually) to be entered into an input field.

The requirements for the field are as follows:

1. Allow `a-z` `A-Z`
2. Allow `0-9`
3. Allow `-` and `.` characters
4. Allow spaces (`\s`)
5. Do **not** allow more than 2 digits
6. Do **not** allow any other special characters

I have managed to put together the following `regex` based on several answers on SO:

```
^(?:([a-zA-z\d\s\.\-])(?!([a-zA-Z]*\d.*){3}))*$
```

The above `regex` is really close. It works successfully for the following:

1. test 12 test
2. test12
3. test-test.12

But it allows an input of:

`123` (but not `1234`, so it's close).

It only needs to allow an input of `12` when **only digits** are entered into the field.

I would like some help in finding a more efficient and cleaner (if possible) solution than my current `regex` - but it must still be `regex`, no `JS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead anchored at the start that will make the match fail once there are 3 digits found anywhere in the string:

```
^(?!(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3})[a-zA-Z0-9\s.-]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R06oW5/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){3})` - the negative lookahead failing the match if exactly 3 following sequences are found:

  - `[^0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than digits
  - `[0-9]` - a digit (thus, the digits do not have to be adjoining)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\s.-]*` - 0+ ASCII letters, digits, whitespace, `.` or `-` symbols
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks, you answered this with some insane speed! Helpful breakdown of the `regex` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a positive lookahead like

```
(?=^(?:\D*\d\D*){2}$) # only two digits
^[- .\w]+$            # allowed characters
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/IZFW83/1/).

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the great answer, I marked Wiktoranswer Stribiżew as correct because he answered first and provided an explanation.... but I am a fan of your solution as well. Does the `positive lookahead` offer any advantages over the `negative look ahead`?

Comment: The pattern is a bit redundant (the lookahead position should be after `^`, and one of them can be removed). The `\w` also matches `_`, and it is not on the list of allowed chars as per the requirements. The positive lookahead `(?=^(?:\D*\d\D*){2}$)` (that must be written as `(?=^(?:\D*\d){2}\D*$)`) *requires* 2 digits to be present in the string, so, the "Do not allow more than 2 digits" requirement is turned into "Must contain 2 digits, no more no less".